# How to get out values from java interface

Tags: java, android, interface, scope

I have a variable inside an interface method and I want it outside the interface:

```
String responseString;
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                // i want this value out!
                responseString = response.toString();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                System.out.println(error.toString());
            }
        });
```

Of course I can't just assign `responseString = response.toString()` because they have different scopes. So how can I do this?

Probably this question has already been answered but I couldn't find anything similar online.

Comment: Of course I can't just assign responseString = response.toString() because they have different scopes. -> what do you mean by that? you mean because they're not in the same class?

Comment: its an asynchronous call . So any further calling u have to make with response should be inside `onResponse` .. you can not get the value out instead u have to wait for response . you can observe the result in this case. there r bunch of options to choose from a callback interface , LiveData , Flow , ObservableField . and yeah this question has been answered like 100 times here .

Answer (score 0):

Try this once as per your JSON  structure Either JSONArray or JSONObject.

```
//JSON Array
    private JSONArray result;

  //Creating a string request
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        JSONObject j = null;
                        try {
                            //Parsing the fetched Json String to JSON Object
                            j = new JSONObject(response);
 
                            //Storing the Array of JSON String to our JSON Array
                            result = j.getJSONArray("your key");
 
                //OPTIONAL function
                            functionName(result);//If using function
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
 
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

The `new Response.Listener<String>() {...}` that you're doing in that method is called "anonymous" implementation. Indeed you are implementing the interface, but you don't hold any static reference to it in the code.

What you should do, is to have a normal implementation of the interface which of course implements the method required, but also holds a field and a special getter for your field:

```
public class YourStringListener implements Response.Listener<String> {

    private String responseString; //<-- declare a field

    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        this.responseString = response.toString(); //<-- set the field
    }

    public String getResponseString() {
        return this.responseString; //<-- get the field from outside
    }

}
```

Now, you should be able to do this:

```
String responseString;
YourStringListener listener = new YourStringListener(); //<-- don't implement anonimously, use the concrete implementation
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, listener, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            System.out.println(error.toString());
        }
    });
System.out.println(listener.getResponseString()); //<-- access the value of response string from the concrete implementation instance
```

Of course, be careful you're into a listener. The value will be `null` until when the method `onResponse` will have asynchronously been called back.